# How to share image to social media with bitmap?

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver, android-recyclerview, android-sharing

I need to share an image from my RecyclerAdapter because the image does not initially exist, i.e. is loaded within the Activity making use of the adapter. How can I share the bitmap to social media? Every time I click share in my app it says "No apps can perform this action".

```
feedItemView.setFeedSocialShareClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Share to Social Media

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) feedItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                Drawable mDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
                Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();

                String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(),
                        mBitmap, "Design", null);

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("image");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I found something cool!");
                context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Your Design!"));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try with

```
 share.setType("image/*");
```

Comment: Fantastic. Wow. That was wracking my brain for a while. Haha. I'll accept answer in 9 minutes when it lets me. Does the /* account for different image extensions?

Comment: exactly. you can define specific types like 'png', 'gif', etc.

Answer (score 0):

In **Kotlin**, if your SDK below 29:
*where you need give the address of your file!*

```
val share = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
          share.type = "image/jpeg"
          share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse(file.path) ) // or Uri.fromFile(file)
          share.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
          share.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"))
```

But if you want cover all **SDK** , it's better use **FileProvider**