# how to share a image bitmap with intent in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

**(This question isn't duplicate !)**

How can I share an image via intent ?

I tried this

[***Android Share Intent for a Bitmap - is it possible not to save it prior sharing?***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30172792/10807406)

***[How to share image to social media with bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966487/how-to-share-image-to-social-media-with-bitmap)***

***[share image with URL android share intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135873/share-image-with-url-android-share-intent)***

but only worked on the emulator and did not work on the actual phone and made the following code error:

```
//b method : convert inputstream to bitmap
String bitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b(inputStream) ,"title", null);
```

Full code :

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open(imageName.getText().toString());
int size = is.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
is.read(buffer);
is.close();
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/" + APP_NAME()+"/pictures/"+ls+"/" ;
new File(path).mkdirs();
String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + imageName.getText().toString().replace("pic/" , "");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(path+fileName));
fileOutputStream.write(buffer);
fileOutputStream.close();
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path+fileName));

String bitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b(inputStream) ,"title", null);
Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM , bitmapUri);
startActivity(intent);


//Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);
//intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
//intent.setType("image/*");
//startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What was the error? Post your full logcat

Comment: try passing String bitmap by using intent.

Comment: logcat image : http://s5.picofile.com/file/8363610718/aa.png

Comment: create a custom `ContentProvider` and override its `openFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mode)` method

Comment: How should I create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved with a small change in my code:

```
Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse (new File (path + fileName) .toString ());
```

Full code :

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open(imageName.getText().toString());
int size = is.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
is.read(buffer);
is.close();
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/" + APP_NAME()+"/pictures/"+ls+"/" ;
new File(path).mkdirs();
String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + imageName.getText().toString().replace("pic/" , "");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(path+fileName));
fileOutputStream.write(buffer);
fileOutputStream.close();
//InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path+fileName));

//String bitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),b(inputStream) ,"title", null); // comment this line
Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(new File(path+fileName).toString()); //changed

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM , bitmapUri);
startActivity(intent);

if (new File(path+fileName).exists()){
    new File(path+fileName).delete();
}
```